# How select email items in a date range using VBA?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

How do I select email items using a specific date range? The user updates a date range via InputBox and emails to be selected automatically.

I tried the below code.

```vb
Sub getEmailsSelected()
    
    Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
    Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim gtStartDate As String
    Dim gtEndDate As String
    
    gtStartDate = InputBox("Type the start date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")
    gtEndDate = InputBox("Type the end date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")
    
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection("[Received] >= '" & gtStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & gtEndDate & "'")
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You may combine Items.Restrict and Explorer.AddToSelection like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub getEmailsSelected()

    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oItems As Items
    Dim i As Long

    Dim gtStartDate As String
    Dim gtEndDate As String

    gtStartDate = InputBox("Type the start date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")
    gtEndDate = InputBox("Type the end date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")

    Set oFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & gtStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & gtEndDate & "'")

    ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection

    For i = 1 To oItems.Count
        ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection oItems(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

To get you started:

[Explorer.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267.aspx) is a read-only property, so your code can't work.

To filter/find items that match your date range, use [Items.Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx) or [Items.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx).

Then you can select the resulting items by calling [Explorer.AddToSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868732.aspx) in a loop.

Comment: thanks for reply , could you please provide me the code  for the above process

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. With the information I gave you, you should be able to find examples and build your own solution. @Oneindiahosting

Comment: You'll be surprised the first accepted answer is giving up code. Be nice to community, please.